# Link directly to video and nothing happens

Tags: html, video, filestream

I'm not sure why I thought the file should be handled by the browser (chrome in my case) and then do something (for chrome I think its use QuickTime to play) but instead I just get an untitled browser title, and the page doesn't actually load, as if its loading an empty html page

anyway the address is:
[www.motionvideos.tv/video/1022_market_review_february_2012_taylors.mp4](http://www.motionvideos.tv/video/1022_market_review_february_2012_taylors.mp4)

Other details which may effect it:
The site uses WordPress, which is currently not functioning, due to someone's fiddling, and will be down for a day or so (stupid zeus server redirects)

The video is just under 9MB.

Possible causes?

Comment: That link downloads directly that mp4 file under Chrome Dev here. Have you tried `<video>` HTML5 tag for embedding that file under WP?

Comment: Works fine with IE, but i tried it with chrome and nothing happened
Maybe chrome cant play that codec or something similar =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link is for video download. 
Do you want it to show on page? 
If so you need to open a HTML page to embed this in.

This is how you embed it via code:
http://www.mediacollege.com/video/format/mpeg4/streaming/example.html

For WP you`ll need to open up a post and use a dedicated plugin for embedding.

Also, you should know that :

1. MP4 is not a universally common codec - some users (many?) will not be able to view it
2. The file itself will load directly from the server, thus noticeably effecting total bandwidth usage (can reflect on site speed, hosting costs and etc)
3. Also not all hosters support (by default) media hosting. This got a lot to do with above mentioned bandwidth issue.

I would suggest re-coding to more common codec + using 3-rd party provider 
(I.E. Flash + Youtube for one is a popular choice but you can also go with AVI + Media Hosting Provider X)

Hope this helps.

Comment: We were going to use flowplayer to show the video on the page, but thats what I meant was on my browser it did nothing, chrome thing i guess, tried with IE and worked fine